# rename clusters according to their major ancestor (pandas.DataFrame;cluster hierarchy)

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am using various clustering algorithms to generate clusters at different resolutions (r1,r2,r3). The results are stored in a pandas.DataFrame that looks like (very simplified example):

```
obs  |r1 |r2 |r3 |r4 |...
----------------------
obs_0| 1 | 3 | 4 |
obs_1| 1 | 3 | 4 |
obs_2| 1 | 3 | 4 |
obs_3| 1 | 1 | 3 |
obs_4| 2 | 2 | 2 |
obs_5| 2 | 2 | 2 |
obs_6| 2 | 2 | 1 |
obs_7| 2 | 2 | 1 |
obs_8| 2 | 2 | 1 |
obs_9| 2 | 2 | 1 |
```

should read:
at r2, cluster 1 splits into 2 clusters (3 and 1)
at r3, cluster 2 splits into 2 clusters (2 and 1)

I would like to renumber these clusters so that the most important child cluster keeps the same name as its ancestor.
Hence, in the provided example:
at r2,
cluster 3 should be relabelled cluster 1 (most ancestors in r1_clu1)
cluster 1 should become cluster 3 (new cluster for that resolution)

at r3,
cluster 4 should be relabelled cluster 1 (ancestors are r2_clu3 aka r1_clu1)
cluster 3 should stay cluster 3
cluster 1 should be renamed cluster 2 (ancestors mainly in r2_clu2)
cluster 2 should be renamed  cluster4 (new cluster for that resolution)
and the resulting DataFrame should be:

```
obs  |r1 |r2 |r3 |r4 |...
----------------------
obs_0| 1 | 1 | 1
obs_1| 1 | 1 | 1
obs_2| 1 | 1 | 1
obs_3| 1 | 3 | 3
obs_4| 2 | 2 | 4
obs_5| 2 | 2 | 4
obs_6| 2 | 2 | 2
obs_7| 2 | 2 | 2
obs_8| 2 | 2 | 2
obs_9| 2 | 2 | 2
```

Note:there may be **more** than one new group for each new resolution.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

I can plot the data with neworkx. basically, i'd like to switch from
[image]
to
[image]
by changing values in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you confirm that the value in your first DataFrame are accurate and explain the use of "res" vs "r"?  For example, you mention that "at res2, cluster 1 splits into 2 clusters (3 and 1)".  I'm assuming that refers to transition from the column labeled "r1" to "r2"?  You also say that "at res3, cluster 2 splits into 2 clusters (2 and 4)", but there is no instance in which a 2 in column "r2" becomes a 4 in column "r3".  Can you clarify what's going on there and explain how the DataFrame should be read?

Comment: Iedited my original post. The dataframes were correct, but as you spotted the explanations were not.

Comment: What happens if there is a tie?  For instance, if at r2, `obs_0` and `obs_1` are in cluster 3 and `obs_2` and `obs_3` are in cluster 1, how should the relabeling work since neither is the "most important" in that case?

Answer (score 0):

finally ended up with the following solutions (but I think there are more elegant ways). This solution seems to work for my data, but may fail on specific cluster configurations (specially merging clusters)

```
    from collections import Counter
    import uuid
    
    def relabel_clusters(df,cols):
        def __automap(src,dst):
            mappings={} ##src->dst
            ## get the largest cluster in dst which parents are c
            for c in sorted(set(src)):
                mappings[c]=Counter(dst[src==c]).most_common(1)[0][0]
            mappings={v:k for k,v in mappings.items() } ##dst->src
            ## search remaining clusters
            extrakeys=[k for k in set(dst) if k not in mappings.keys()]
            extravalues=[v for v in set(dst) if v not in mappings.values()]
            mappings.update(dict(zip(extrakeys,extravalues)))
            return mappings
        
        for i in range(1,len(cols)):
            ## for some unknown reason, this line does not work.
            #df[cols[i]]=df[cols[i]].replace( automap(df[cols[i-1]],df[cols[i]]))
            ## we need to perform two successive mappings, which seems to work with my "real" data
            mappings=__automap(df[cols[i-1]],df[cols[i]])
            uuids=[uuid.uuid4() for k in mappings.keys()]
            map1=dict(zip(mappings.keys(),uuids))
            map2=dict(zip(uuids,mappings.values()))
            tmp=df[cols[i]].replace( map1 )
            df[cols[i]]=tmp.replace( map2 ) 
    
    ## main program
    s0=pd.Series([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]).rename('s0')
    s1=pd.Series([3,3,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]).rename('s1')
    s2=pd.Series([4,4,4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1]).rename('s2')
    s3=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]).rename('untouched')
    
    df=pd.DataFrame({s.name:s for s in [s0,s1,s2,s3]})
    print("original :\n",df)
    relabel_clusters(df,['s0','s1','s2'])  
    print("remapped :\n",df)
```

Illustration on fake data (before->after):
[image]
and real data (before->after)
[image]